# How to execute linux program from PHP?

Tags: php, linux, exec

I would like to execute a linux program from php, how can I do that ?

In linux terminal, I usually do :

```
./program_name -o argument1 -f argument2 -out argument3
```

How can I do that in PHP ?

Comment: Why can't you simply `exec ('/path/to/program/ -o argument1 -f argument2 -out argument3');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried exec() ? shell_exec() ?  system() ?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

You should also have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php about escaping special characters.
You'll also have to make sure that the Linux user running php/apache and so on, has the needed rights to run system commands.

Comment: yes. I tried, but nothing seemed to happen. I am confused in how to pass the parameters. And the working directory of php is different from where the linux program is located

Comment: Use the full path of the program. Check your system error logs to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) function.

```
<?php
  $output = shell_exec('/path/to/program_name -o argument1 -f argument2 -out argument3');
  echo $output;
?>
```